# pygame how to get a key_event from char

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am in the process of creating a game, and I want to let the user to customize the buttons.

for now I created a function that takes a string and gives you a key event back:

```
def key_events(char):
    if char='a':
        return pygame.K_a
```

and so on for all the characters.

there is probably an easier way to do this but i am unable to find it. can someone guide me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of mapping buttons, when you're asking them to press the button they want to map, you can take the event.key from the KEYDOWN event.  You shouldn't need to have a string involved.

Comment: I...should've thought about that. upvoted and accepted.